How can I tell the unknown owner/view to disconnect from the shared NSColorPanel?
I'm working on the custom NSTableCellView that will be used in the complex system alongside with the other custom views, provided by other developers/teams/etc. So, I don't know which components/views will be around my view at runtime.
In my code I use NSColorPanel (without the NSColorWell) to provide color editing capabilities. I also add my custom controls into the NSColorPanel using the accessoryView.
This works fine, but I can't understand how my code is supposed to transfer the control of the NSColorPanel to/from other views that may also want to use the panel (such as NSColorWell or other custom views).
Let's look at the following (simplified) example: the window containing the NSButton, the NSTextField (called txt) and the NSColorWell. The Button and the TextField will represent my view (over which I have full control)  and the ColorWell will represent the 3-rd party view (other custom table cell view), over which I have no control.
The button click handler that shows the NSColorPanel and adds the custom view to it:
@IBAction func showColorPicker(_ sender: Any) 
{
    let colorPanel = NSColorPanel.shared
    colorPanel.accessoryView = makeAccessoryView()
    colorPanel.setTarget(self)
    colorPanel.setAction(#selector(OnColorChanged))
    colorPanel.delegate = nil
    colorPanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
}

func makeAccessoryView() -> NSView
{
    let emptyColorButton = NSButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 30))
    emptyColorButton.title = "Empty/non-set color"
    emptyColorButton.target = self
    emptyColorButton.action = #selector(onEmptyColorButtonClicked)

    let accessoryView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 30))
    accessoryView.addSubview(emptyColorButton)
   
    return accessoryView
}

@objc func OnColorChanged(_ sender: NSObject)
{
    let color = (sender as! NSColorPanel).color
    txt.stringValue = color.description;
}

@objc func onEmptyColorButtonClicked()
{
    txt.stringValue = "Button inside NSColorPanel was clicked";
}

Let' follow the steps:

Run the application
Click the ColorWell and select a color - only the ColorWell is affected at the moment.
Click the Button and select a color - now both the ColorWell and the TextField are affected (and this is a problem)
Click the ColorWell again, then click the Empty/non-set color button inside the ColorPanel - although the ColorWell owns the panel, the (logically unrelated) TextField is changed.

The desired behaviour will be the following:

When my code takes control of the NSColorPanel (when the button is clicked), the other users of the panel are notified and can detach from the panel (I mean some kind of standard, well-known notification that is will be supported by the standard NSColorWell and any other well-designed control).
When other code takes control of the NSColorPanel, my code will be notified and will be able to detach any handlers and remove the custom content from the accessoryView

Note: In the real code I don't have direct access to NSColorWell and can't just call colorWell.deactivate().

Which object is first responder? How does the user know which cell is being mutated?

In the simplified example the first responder will be the button or the NSColorWell. In the real code - the custom view inside my NSTableCellView. From the user's point of view you click the desired cell/button/colorWell then work with a NSColorPanel. And the only view that was clicked the last should be mutated.

There is no standard, well-known notification. If you don't want to share the color panel then you'll have to implement this yourself. Note: it is possible to activate multiple NSColorWells, NSColorWell doesn't own the panel. There are NSColorWells on the font panel.

if you can't collaborate with the other controls in the app then a workaround might be to "own" the panel while your cell or custom view is first responder. You can deactivate other NSColorWells by activating a dummy free floating NSColorWell.

@Willeke, thank you for the idea with the dummy NSColorWell, it works (so, it looks like the some kind of notification really exists, but unfortunately it is not public). So, the only part I have to implement to become happy - it is a control transfer from my view to the other (so I will be able to remove the custom button from inside the NSColorPanel). I'll try to play with a notification, related to the first responder changes.

For anyone who can find this later: no luck with a first responder tracking. In my experiments, the reliability of tracking is very dependent on the other controls the user is communicating with. So, no reliable and environment-independent solution was found.

Are becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder not called?

becomeFirstResponder is called perfectly for the views I control, but resignFirstResponder (which I'm most interested in) is called or not depending on which view the user clicks/selects after my view. Since I can't control or even know about the views around me, it looks like the resignFirstResponder is useless for my task.
